# Hibernate @ManyToMany joinTable - OrderBy using join table's field

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, join, joincolumn

There are 3 tables:

TABLE_A
ID_A
field1
fieldN

TABLE_B
ID_B
field1
fieldN

TABLE_A_B
ID_A
ID_B
orderField

```
public class A(){
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="TABLE_A_B", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_A")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_B")})
    @OrderBy(value="orderField")
    private List<TABLE_B> BList;
}
```

But it isn't working, instead I get a runtime error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column B1_.orderField doesn't exist Position: 1437
```

Hibernate searches the field in TABLE_B. Is it possible to use "OrderBy" in a many to many relationship using a join table's field? Or any other way to get to order based in the same field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is correct, did you try that, it will work. One problem is that you are using `list` so while you having that list in cache probably wouldn't be sorted, but if you clear current session and fetch it again it will be ordered as you set with `@OrderBy(value="orderField")`.

Also there is another issue with `@OrderBy` regarding to a hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#d5e5328);

> Lists can be mapped in two different ways:
>
> - as ordered lists, where the order is not materialized in the database
> - as indexed lists, where the order is materialized in the database
>
> To order lists in memory, add @javax.persistence.OrderBy to your
>   property.

But I've just tried your problem and query on database has order by parameter (`hibernate.show_sql=true`), so I'm not sure what they meant with upper statement.

My query example;

```
select ... from ... inner join ... where users0_.event_id=? order by user1_.fullname
```

I'll conclude, if ordering is done on database then you can safely use @OrderBy annotation.

**UPDATE:**

`@OrderBy` should have native sql value, for example;

```
@OrderBy(value="orderField")
private List<TABLE_B> BList;
```

where `orderField` is database name of the column in table `TABLE_B`, also it is possible to do this `@OrderBy(value="lower(fullname) desc")`

If you want to create column in join TABLE_A_B which keeps same order as it is in your list in java, then you should use `@OrderColumn(name="orderField")`

Try this;

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="TABLE_A_B", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_A")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_B")})
@OrderColumn(name="orderField")
private List<TABLE_B> BList;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the example that I have posted doens't work. I have a runtime error: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column B1_.orderField doesn't exist
  Position: 1437`

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to use a join table's field, to order the values. I updated my question.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I've just tried to confirm my thoughts. Did you try with @OrderColumn?

Comment: It does not work when reading the newly arranged items from the DB, as `@OrderBy` sorts by composite ID and not by the intermediate column `orderField` (which might be a simple integer, 1, 2, 3, ...