# Order by using intermediate table column in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, join

I have Class Product (corresponding to **PRODUCT** table)

```
Class Product {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "NAME")
     private String name;

     //other attributes
}
```

I have another class Owner (corresponding to **OWNER** table)

```
Class Owner{
     @Id
     @Column(name = "OWNER_ID")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "NAME")
     private String name;
}
```

I have an intermediate table named **PRODUCT_OWNER** (a product can have multiple owners).

The PRODUCT_OWNER table is something like this.

```
 _______________________________________
| PRODUCT_ID | OWNER_ID | DISPLAY_ORDER |
|____________|__________|_______________|
```

Inside my Product class I have written a join statement to perform join using intermediate PRODUCT_OWNER table

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Owner.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_OWNER", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID") })
private Set<Owner> productOwners = new HashSet<Owner>(0);
```

I have a column in my intermediate table as **DISPLAY_ORDER**. I want to sort the final Set **productOwners** using **DISPLAY_ORDER**. Is this possible in above approach. Please advice.

Comment: Please let me know if anything is not clear here, instead of downvoting.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that is doing a bad order or some exception? Anyway i think if your intermediate table have some extra column, maybe you could consider create an entity for it

Comment: So where is this "DISPLAY_ORDER" being populated from? because JPA is not managing it. And if JPA is not managing it then you aren't going to order by it

Comment: Edited my question. @cralfaro I want the final set order as per the intermediate table column "DISPLAY_ORDER".

Comment: And my reply still stands. You CANNOT have some arbitrary extra column in a join table that JPA doesn't know about and isn't populating.

Comment: @NeilStockton well. JPA doesnt know about the PRODUCT_OWNER table either. Still we are able to use it to join 2 tables. FYI. I am new to JPA, still in learning phase. Please correct me if I am getting something wrong here.

Comment: Of course it _knows_ about the PRODUCT_OWNER table ... it's in your JPA metadata! I __have corrected you__ since you are getting something wrong here. You can't have arbitrary extra columns that WILL NOT BE POPULATED. If you want that column then you introduce a new Entity to represent the data in that table

Comment: @Vivek maybe you could have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051764/hibernate-manytomany-jointable-orderby-using-join-tables-field

Comment: OK. Understood. Thanks for the help. I'll create an entity for intermediate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try to add this to your JoinTable

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Owner.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_OWNER", 
       joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID") }, 
       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID") })
@OrderColumn(name="DISPLAY_ORDER")
private List<Owner> productOwners = new HashSet<Owner>(0);
```